# Remove multi-language storeview code from the url - Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, store-view, language

I am using Magento multistore view for multiple languages like `english`, `german`, `french` etc.

To have clean urls i have enabled the settings **"Add Store Code to Urls"** to **"yes"**.

Now it shows following url for stores:

> English: mystore.com/english/category1.html
>
> German:  mystore.com/german/category1.html

English language store is my default store. it loads when my site load first.
as it's default language i don't want to show  english in the url.

So how can i remove the english from the default store view url?

The url for english should be:

> English: http://mystore.com/category1.html
>
> German: http://mystore.com/german/category1.html

Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

> https://github.com/jreinke/magento-hide-default-store-code

Remove this format: `?___store=english for english and ?___store=arabic`

In the design file find the languages.phtml

```
/app/design/frontend/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml
```

**In the line 41**

```
echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl()

Add 'false' as parameter

echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false)
```

**Actual Url:**

```
http:example.com?___store=english for english and ?___store=arabic
```

After added the false parameter in `$_lang->getCurrentUrl(false)` method. Url will be generated like the below

> http:example.com?___store=english

Comment: i  already tried this extension. it shows 404 for my english store. Did reindex but still showing 404.  also,  already did  false paramaters that's the reason getting clean url.

Comment: Did you Find Solution?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is work fine for me.
I just add one line to model observer, and 404 is not showing.

```
$requestUri = str_replace('index.php/', '/', $requestUri);
```